# Prove that if $P:A:V\to W$ is perpendicular projection to the subspace of U, then id$-P$ is perpendicular projection to U⊥.

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm struggling with the following problem and need help with it.

Let $U$ is the subspace of inner product space $V$. I have to prove that if $P:A:V\to W$ is perpendicular projection to the subspace U, then id$-P$ is perpendicular projection to the subspace U⊥.

I can't for the life of me get it done so I'd appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

i think is something like that:
$$ V=U \oplus U_\perp \ni v=u+u_\perp$$
$$(\text{Id}-P)v=v-P(v)=u+u_\perp  - u =u_\perp$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.